# How to trim an unwanted continuous string at end in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, trim

I am trying to trim a string with unnecessary characters at the end as below.
I would appreciate either if someone corrects me or provide me an easy approach!!

Expected Result: `finalString, Hello ---- TecAdmin`

```js
const longStr = "Hello ---- TecAdmin------------";

function trimString(str) {
  const lastChar = str[str.length - 1];
  if(lastChar === '-') {
   str = str.slice(0, -1);
   trimString(str);
  } else {
   console.log(str,'finally')
   return str;
  }
}

const finalString = trimString(longStr);

console.log('finalString', finalString)
```

Comment: and `longStr.replace(/-+/g, '')` doesnt work?

Comment: @Deryck Thanks for replying, In my case i may have '----'  in the middle of the string.
I dont wanna remove the hyphens in the middle

Comment: how many do you not want to remove?

Comment: `longStr.replace(/-{5,}/g, '')`

Comment: see new answer :)

Comment: Can't we trim only at the end defining the unwanted element using regex? @Deryck

Comment: @sumanth use `$` anchor, which means end of the string, `.replace(/-+$/g,'')` this will trim all the `-` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working off Deryck's comments & answer, but allowing for any number of dashes on the end:

```js
const longStr = "Hello ---- TecAdmin------------";
var thing = longStr.replace(/-*$/g, '');
console.log(thing);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out - replace only 5 or more -

```
longStr.replace(/-{5,}/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

use split to split the string into an array, then use pop however many times to remove characters at the end. you can test the last character each time and use pop if its a "-"

```
//js
const longStr = "Hello ---- TecAdmin------------";
let splitLongStr = longStr.split('');

for (let i=0; i<splitLongStr.length; i++) {
  splitLongStr.pop();
}

let longStrChopped = splitLongStr.join('');
```

Comment: this works, i just tested in a node JS env. it might leave you with one left over dash, just modify how many times you run the loop `i<...` and have fun! problem solved